# Projects got affected while installing laravel

Tags: php, macos, laravel, mamp

While installing laravel through terminal command, my other projects in MAMP htdocs folder got affected and they are not working. 
[I followed this process for installing laravel](http://blog.jboyd.co/quickly-setup-laravel-to-work-in-mamp/)

Comment: Those directions have you link the "htdocs" directory to your laravel install, effectively making your `htdocs` directly useful only for Laravel. You should avoid this, perhaps by linking a directory within htdocs. For example, linking to a directory in htdocs called "mylaravelapp":  `ln -s /path/to/laravel-master /path/to/htdocs/mylaravelapp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those directions have you [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) the "htdocs" directory to your laravel install, effectively making your `htdocs` directly useful only for Laravel.

You should avoid this, perhaps by creating a symlink from your laravel build to a directory **within** htdocs. For example, linking to a directory in htdocs called "mylaravelapp":  `ln -s /path/to/laravel-master /path/to/htdocs/mylaravelapp`.

Lastly, consider using [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) or another virtual machine provider instead of MAMP for a server. You'll have to get through a learning curve (potentially), but you'll end up better for it. This creates a virtual server for you, which won't interact with any other parts of your Mac (YOu can make a server per project!).

[Here is a guide](http://culttt.com/2013/06/17/setting-up-vagrant-with-laravel-4/) to get started with Laravel 4 and Vagrant.